# Get the specific column involved in a FK Exception

Tags: java, mysql, spring, exception, foreign-keys

I faced with the follow message error (DataIntegrityViolationException) in an attempt of delete a specific record in my table:

`Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (company.table_parent, CONSTRAINT table_parent_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (id_son) REFERENCES layout (id))`

I already know the cause: I'm attempting to delete a record, however, it is being used in other table.

I'd like to know if exist a attribute that contains the table and the column involved in transaction attempt, order to I could treat properly the exception without check the error message content.

Comment: The answer is in your error message you posted. You want to know BEFORE the delete attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this call is included in an outer wrapped transaction. as I see it you can:

(A) make the call and parse the error message. You will know the table/col of violation.

(B) query for existence in FK table (either parent or child) for columns suspected of subsequent violation before the update/delete call.

another way of looking at B is that you might be doing this against the parent table and it is a child table that is barking saying you are about to orphan me

Comment: I bet the second way is the only solution for me. Is what I actually have used in my code. But I expected that I could infer the specific cause directly from the exception, without this previous checking. Tks, anyway.

Comment: Well the error string tells you and can be parsed and acted upon thru code (whatever you might do in an automated way)